# Can you tell if a C++ project has been buit previously in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

Is there a way to understand if a C++ Project has been Build previously in Eclipse?

I have to rebuild some projects sometime because I can not tell if it has been build before. And this process takes a lot of time.

Comment: You could simply `make` these projects. If their build is current, that should not last much.

Comment: in which directory should I perform the `make` command? In the directory where the `makefile` is?

Comment: Probably yes, in the directory containing the `Makefile` ... BTW, I don't think that using Eclipse is good for you (and you could use an editor like `emacs` and use `make` for building).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will get to know. when you click build and it was successful, and later you make some changes, and get error, you can go back to your last build configuration. You also can build it automatically, when you save.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP wants to know if all the current C++ code has been built or not.